# indentation is causing issues while sending email in a method

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to send an email using Pythion smtp library. I have got below code but somehow when I get an email, it doesn't have `"To"`, `"Subject"` and `"Body"` contents as they are missing. I believe something is wrong with the way `message` string is constructed.

```
import smtplib
import socket

FROM = "from@host.com"
TO = ["to@host.com"]

def send_email():
    hostname = socket.getfqdn()
    text = "Hello"
    subject = "Error on %s " % (hostname)
    print subject

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), subject, text)

    smtp_server = ""
    if ".dev" not in hostname:
        smtp_server = "abc.host.com"
    else:
        smtp_server = "pqr.host.com"

    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()

send_email()
```

But when I use exact same below code, it works fine without any issues so I am sure something is wrong with my above code when I put everything in a method. I believe indentation is causing issues with the way message string is contructed or something else which I am not able to figure out.

```
import smtplib
import socket

SERVER = "abc.host.com"

FROM = "from@host.com"
TO = ["to@host.com"]
SUBJECT = "Test! %s " % (socket.getfqdn())
TEXT = "Testing."

# Prepare actual message

message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join( TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

Here is what I see with first code. If you see closely it has lot of spaces in front of each tag as compared to what gets printed out with second code:

```
    From: from@host.com
    To: to@host.com
    Subject: Error on machineA

    Hello
```

This is what I see with second code:

```
From: from@host.com
To: to@host.com
Subject: Test! machineA

Testing.
```

How do I fix this in first code when I am putting it in a method?

**Update:**

I tried with below code but it gives me error about indentation is wrong on `print message`.

```
import smtplib
import socket

FROM = "from@host.com"
TO = ["to@host.com"]

def send_email():
    hostname = socket.getfqdn()
    text = "Hello"
    subject = "Error on %s " % (hostname)
    print subject

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), subject, text)

    print message
    smtp_server = ""
    if ".dev" not in hostname:
        smtp_server = "abc.host.com"
    else:
        smtp_server = "pqr.host.com"

    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()

send_email()
```

Comment: Your literal 'three-quote' string in the function includes the indents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowed to remove the indents:

```
def send_email():
    # stuff ...

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """\
From: %s
- other stuff...

""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), subject, text)

    smtp_server = ""

    # more stuff...
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
```

Also, not sure you need the back slash?

```
message = '''    < == no backslash
stuff
'''
```

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion but it gives me error on indentation while compiling? Anything wrong in my updated code?

Comment: It still sounds like there is something wrong with the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the stdlib `email`package to help you building your mail as correct SMTP payloads (headers, encoding, parts, ...). https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html#module-email

There are tons of examples in the standard doc or in stackoverflow.